# Could OpenCV compile/use with WASI(WebAssembly System Interface)?

Tags: c++, opencv, webassembly, wasi

WASI (WebAssembly System Interface) is intended to bring WebAssembly outside the browser.

I built a simple face recognition application with the eigenfaces example of OpenCV 4.3.0 (See: https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/facerec_tutorial.html#eigenfaces-in-opencv) and made it work.

Recently I would like to build a WebAssembly(WASM)-based face recognition application with OpenCV. I searched for WASM+face recognition and I got lots of git repositories and examples with `opencv_js.wasm` and uses it with a JavaScript binding.

My purpose is to build a standalone *.wasm module rather than html+js+wasm project, hence I ran into WASI(WebAssembly System Interface). Several runtimes such as `wasmtime` and `wasmer` could run standalone *.wasm which is compiled from C/C++ with an WASI toolchain(`wasicc`, `wasic++`, etc., such as `wasienv` project).

Have you guys have any ideas or experiences to build a standalone face recognition/detection/... or similar projects with WASI? Really appreciate for your reply!